# Contextual Filter not working wiht URL aliases

Tags: views, 8, path-aliases

I have this issue with contextual filter. I have set the filter so it would get an ID of an article and based on that ID, it would show the name of the author.
The problem is, it doesnt work with URL aliases.
For example, when I put the ID of the node like **example.com/node/22**, it finds the author. But when I try to put the URL alias like **example.com/clanky/something-something-something**, it doesnt show anything.
Any idea how can I solve this?
Thank you for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use Content ID from URL instead of Raw value from URL

[image]

Comment: I did that before, it still doesnt work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Hard to believe, should've worked...

Comment: I added few relationships to get the content ID, do you think that the relationships might be the problem?

Comment: @AdamŠulc maybe, you could try removing them for testing purposes and add content id as a field. The view should display the id number.

Comment: @AdamŠulc check your view block's configuration visibility setttings, maybe you have it set to only show on `/node/*`.

Comment: well the thing is, I can see the block on the site, it is just empty and not showing what it should show due to the collision with URL aliases.

Comment: strip your site's css with a browser tool like [web developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) and see if you can see it, to make sure there is no js or css file that's hidding it.

Comment: Thats not the case either.